# Using Keras/ Neural Networks for categorical data

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

In the [CNN example for the minst dataset for Keras](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py) they tell you how to make a good CNN network to recognise hand written digits. The issue is that it doesn't tell you how to predict new digits.

For example give an image, if I do this:

```
model.predict(image)
```

instead of telling me what digits it think it is, it instead gives me a list of 10 numbers (presumably probabilities)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use numpy's argmax to find out class that has maximum probability

```
import numpy as np
probabilities = model.predict(image)
classes = np.argmax(probabilities, axis=-1)
```

Comment: What if I sent in an array of images instead of a single image?

Comment: That will be okay, since output probabilities will have size of `[N_images,10]`, and argmax is picking maximum index along the last dimension (because of `axis = -1`)